# Django Integration tests for urls

Tags: python, django, integration-testing

I have a django app I wanted to write tests for. For now Im writing integration tests for the urls.

For my `signin` test , my url looks like:
`url(r'^signin/$', login_forbidden(signin), name='signin')`

and my test looks like:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class SigninTest(TestCase):
    def test_signin(self):
        resp = self.client.get('/signin/')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

However I have no idea to test a a longer url, for instance I have one entry in urls like:

```
url(
        r'^ad_accounts/(?P<ad_account_id>[^/]+)/$',
        AdAccountDetailView.as_view(),
        name='campaigns'
    ),
```

If I repeat the above test I have for the signin page (replacing `resp = self.client.get('/ad_accounts/')`) returns a failure

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_signin (engineoftravel.tests.SigninTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/project/tests.py", line 7, in test_signin
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 302 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.103s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use reverse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

....
resp = self.client.get(reverse('campaigns', args=[1]))
```

where args is the id you need to pass in.

EDIT: since django 1.10 reverse imports from django.urls

Comment: gives this `ImportError: No module named urls`

Comment: from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

if you have an earlier version of django

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 
client = Client()
class MainTest(TestCase):
    ##user login in django
    def user_login(self, username, password):
        response = self.client.login(username=username, password=username)
        return self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
   ## first case
   def detail(self):
     response = self.client.get('/ad_accounts/<test_num>/') ## url regex
     self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

   def detail2(self):
       response = self.client.get(reverse('campaigns'))
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the test failure, you should first [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) with some test user then make a request, otherwise the page will be redirected to the login page and thus you will get a 302 status code.

Also you can test the status code of the redirected page with `client.get('/foo', follow=True)` which returns the status code of the sign in page. (In your example)